# I am creating a tkinter UI for my python program. However, I have an issue with the tk.button. It underlines my image button line

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, tkinter

Here is the program I have written so far...

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont
from tkinter.ttk import *

app = tk.Tk()
app.geometry("400x200")

photo = app.PhotoImage(file = r"C:\ex\ex.png")

tk.Label(app, text='Ex', font=(
    'Verdana', 15)).pack(side=tk.TOP, pady=10)
app.iconbitmap(r'C:\Users\ex\ex_icon.ico')

ex_activation_button = tk.Button(app,
                                 image = photo).pack(side = TOP),
                                 width=20,
                                 height=10)

app.title("Not working Photo Button")
ex_activation_button.pack(side=tk.TOP)

app.mainloop()
```

I have been trying to get an image based button which also allows me to click and run a seperate python program. The very first step was setting up the image based button. If anyone has an idea of what I am doing wrong, please let me know. I would greatly appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use `app.PhotoImage`.Use `tk.PhotoImage` instead,also you add unnecessary `image = photo).pack(side = TOP),` in your code.

Try this code below:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont
from tkinter.ttk import *

app = tk.Tk()
app.geometry("400x200")

photo = tk.PhotoImage(file = r"C:\ex\ex.png")

tk.Label(app, text='Ex', font=(
    'Verdana', 15)).pack(side=tk.TOP, pady=10)
app.iconbitmap(r'C:\Users\ex\ex_icon.ico')

ex_activation_button = tk.Button(app,
                                 image = photo,
                                 width=20,
                                 height=10)

app.title("Not working Photo Button")
ex_activation_button.pack(side=tk.TOP)

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: This worked! I will accept the answer and upvote but I had one more question. How can I have it so that the button runs a python program when clicked. I did want to do this in one program.

Comment: @RedgarPro Maybe you need to create a `tk.Toplevel()` to create a new window.